# jQuery replace HTML formatted words in HTML text

Tags: jquery, replace

I have a editable div:

```
<div id="artikel" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

It works nice, I can edit it on the fly by just typing in it.

What I now want is to search in the text typed in, just when they lift a key:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#artikel").live("keyup", function(e)
    {
        var text = $(this).html();
        console.log(text);
    });
});
</script>
```

This is all working.

The question is, when I have this text:

> Sampele **text** with the same words in the **text**.

How to only replace the first "text" word and not the second one. And how to let the HTML bold intact.

Comment: Please note that `live()` is [deprecated in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Use `on()` instead (or `delegate()` before 1.7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This replace the 'text' string by newText, only once :

```
var $t = $('#artikel');
var html = $t.html();
var i = html.indexOf('text');
html = html.substring(0, i) + newText + html.substring(i+'text'.length);
$t.html(html);
```